# Capturing scalar variable in Perl Tk radiobutton form

Tags: perl, perltk

I am trying to capture the value of the marked radio button after submit is pressed but can't seem to get it to work. What I would like is for the form/window to close when submit is pressed and for the value marked to be saved and sent to the store_it subroutine so that it can be used.

```
use strict;
use Tk;
my $mw = MainWindow->new;

# default
my $determined = 'games';

# get menu options from directories
my $dir_lib = '/usr/local/';
my @options = `ls $dir_lib`;
chomp @options;
s{^\s+|\s+$}{}g foreach @options;

$mw->title("Confirm Determination");
$mw->label("Pick category.");
$mw->configure();

my $chosen;
my $confirmed;
#create radio buttons based on file types
foreach (@options) {

    my $chosen = $dir_lib . $_;
    
    $mw->Radiobutton(
    -text      => $_,
    -value     => $_,
    -variable  => \$determined,
    -justify   => 'left',
    -padx      => 30,
    -pady      => 10
            
    )->pack( -anchor => 'w' );

    
} # end of foreach

$mw->Button(-text => "Submit",
        -command => \&store_it($chosen))->pack();


MainLoop;
###################
sub store_it {
##################    

    my ($fts)  = @_; 
    print "Will store $fts\n";
    
####################    
} # EOS store it
####################
```

Instead the form stays active and I get the following output:

```
Use of uninitialized value $fts in concatenation (.) or string at Tk_radio_menu.pl line 50.
Will store 
Tk::Error: Undefined subroutine &main::1 called at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.34/Tk.pm line 251.
 Tk callback for .button
 Tk::__ANON__ at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.34/Tk.pm line 251
 Tk::Button::butUp at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.34/Tk/Button.pm line 175
 <ButtonRelease-1>
 (command bound to event)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use an anonymous sub which calls `store_it()` with the value of `$determined`, e.g.:

```
# ... this part of the script is as before
my $confirmed;
#create radio buttons based on file types
foreach (@options) {
    $mw->Radiobutton(
    -text      => $_,
    -value     => $_,
    -variable  => \$determined,
    -justify   => 'left',
    -padx      => 30,
    -pady      => 10
    )->pack( -anchor => 'w' );    
} # end of foreach

$mw->Button(-text => "Submit",
        -command => sub {store_it($determined)})->pack();


MainLoop;
###################
sub store_it {
##################

    my ($fts)  = @_;
    print "Will store $fts\n";

####################
} # EOS store it
####################
```